# numpy array divide multiple columns by one column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is it possible to divide multiple numpy array columns by another 1D column (row wise division)?

Example:

```py
a1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
a2 = np.array([11,12,13])
array([11, 12, 13])
# that is divide all rows, but only columns 1 and 2 by a2 array
a1[:,:2] / a2
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,2) (3,)
```

I did try this, but this does not look elegant

```py
(a1[:,:2].T / a2).T
array([[0.09090909, 0.18181818],
       [0.33333333, 0.41666667],
       [0.53846154, 0.61538462]])
```

Comment: So, what would the right answer be for your sample data?

Comment: Did you mean something like this `a1[:,:2] / a2[:2]`?

Comment: Hey Soroush i did and just realize that was also the issue, but i did need column wise which i thought the double transpose was crummy

Comment: By the `rules of broadcasting` the second array needs to be (3,1) shape.  The default expansion to 2d is (1,3), which is not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your a1 array is 2D and a2 is 1D, try expanding the dimension of a2 array to 2D before performing division:

```py
>>> a1[:,:2]/np.expand_dims(a2, 1)

array([[0.09090909, 0.18181818],
       [0.33333333, 0.41666667],
       [0.53846154, 0.61538462]])
```

Apparently, you can just use `a2[:, None]` instead of calling `expand_dims` function for even cleaner code.

Comment: Another way to do `expand_dims` is by adding `None` to a slice: `a2[:,None]`.

Comment: @Blckknght, yes but it may not be explicitly clear for those who are just getting started with numpy.

Comment: I agree, explicit is often better!

Comment: awesome, thanks. I'll accept this once the 5min countdown is done :)

Comment: oh @Blckknght i really like your answer, that to me is pretty clear since all i do is slice